# Indexing and searching number field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have created the following collection and text index:

```
db.test1.insert({"name":"kumar goyal","email":'rakesh.goyal@gmail.com',"phoneNo":9742140651});
db.test1.ensureIndex({ "$**": "text" },{ name: "TextIndex" })
```

Partial search is working for name and email field e.g.

```
db.test1.runCommand("text",{search:'rakesh'});
```

returns the record properly but its not working on the `phoneNo` field.

```
db.test1.runCommand("text",{search:'9742'});
```

is not working.

I guess text index is not working on number fields. Is there anyway to make it work in mongodb?

Answer (score 2):

You are inserting the telephone number as a number, but then searching for it as a string.

Perhaps you should consider inserting the telephone number as a string. You're not planning to perform any arithmetic actions on that field are you?

This way mongo will be able to perform textual searches (like the one you gave as an example) on the "numbers" but will treat them as strings.

Comment: Its not working even if I insert the data like this db.test1.insert({"name":"kumar goyal","email":'rakesh.goyal@gmail.com',"phoneNo":"9742140651"});

Answer (score 0):

Mongo DB full text does not support partial search. Hence it was not working, nothing to do with numbers.

Comment: Why are you trying to do text search on phone numbers, it is a bit of an odd thing actually. Normally you want to split the phone numbner into area code and actual number, intergise them and then search by tokens of it via $gt and $lt